# Getting error signing iOS ipa for Flutter Build on Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: ios, flutter, azure-devops

Here is my flutter build command:

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs 
flutter build ipa --release --flavor LaoYouHui --dart-define=ENV=DEV --no-sound-null-safety
```

On developer's Mac computer, where cert and provision file are configured in Keychain, the command works fine and produces the ipa file.
I'm trying to get it to work on my Azure pipeline. But I'm getting the below error:

```
error: No profiles for 'cn.com.XXXXX.XX.cpulse' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'cn.com.XXXXX.XX.cpulse'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

More details about my Azure pipeline:

Agent is this:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-10.15'
```

This is how I provided cert and provision file:

```
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
        displayName: 'Install an DevApple certificate'
        inputs:
          certSecureFile: 'dev.p12'
          certPwd: 'XXXXXXXX'
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
        inputs:
          provProfileSecureFile: 'cpulse_dev.mobileprovision'
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have for the iOS part:

```
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
          inputs:
            certSecureFile: 'myCert.p12'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
          inputs:
            provProfileSecureFile: 'development.mobileprovision'

- task: FlutterBuild@0
          displayName: "Build IOS IPA"
          inputs:
            target: 'ios'
            projectDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
            iosCodesign: false
```

Maybe also double check your certificate and provisioning profile, if you unlocked all permissions to actually use it in those cases.
Another thing to check is if you put your Certificate in Temporary, Default or Custom keychain, I have it in Temporary.

Comment: Thank you for helping! I see in your "FlutterBuild" task, you have "iosCodesign" as "false", so does this task produce an ipa file that's not signed? If not could you explain what's the result of your "FlutterBuild" task?